# Save sprite content as .png file with cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I need to create an empty sprite as a container and add there in different positions different sprites created by using different images. At the end I need to save the result which in added as child into the container sprite as an image - .png for example.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RenderTexture and call visit method of Sprite. Here is a sample code:

```
RenderTexture* renderTexture = RenderTexture::create(width, height, Texture2D::PixelFormat::RGBA8888);
renderTexture->begin();
sprite->visit();
renderTexture->end();
renderTexture->saveToFile("snapshot.png", Image::Format::PNG);
```

Comment: Thank you Vikas :). Could you please explain what does `visit` do?

Comment: `CCNode::visit()` will cause recursive draw of children's so that `RenderTexture` can grab it. You need to visit all nodes which you want to capture, otherwise it will save a black PNG image.

Comment: I have used this code on Android and cannot find the image. I have printed `FileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath()` and it is equal to `/data/data/com.test.cakepop/files/`. I thought that the file may be there, but Astro File Managers says that `/data` is empty.

Comment: I tested it on iOS and was working fine inside `init()` method but not worked on Windows. It's working only inside `onEnter()` method. Check thread here : http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/c2d-x-3-0-spritebatchnode-rendertexture-error/13366/2

Comment: It works on Android, and it writes in getWriteablePath. I just can not see or find it. Do I need a superuser on my device to see `/data/data/com.test.cakepop/files/`?

Comment: In other words I have here two problems. I cannot find the file saved on Android. And I don't know how to change the path to a place I desire. Could you please help me on this too.

Comment: Given path is isolated storage of application and I think you can not access directly.The best thing you can do is write a helper callback function in your Android Activity to read image from application data path and then save it to some where else in SD Card using Android I/O api.

Comment: What you mean by saying a helper callback function?

Comment: A JNI function (C++ to Java) in Activity.